# How can I add new orderNode on running hyperLedgerFabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, ibm-blockchain

I have setup a hyperledger fabric network with 1 orderer node, but i want to  know how to add new  orderer node to a running production hyperledger network using  Solo conesuss algorithm

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

As the name `Solo` implies, it's a single entity so you can't add another ordering node. You would never use Solo for production either. You should use raft which can have multiple ordering nodes (but you need to understand the implications of multiple ordering nodes using raft so definitely refer to the hyperledger fabric documentation).

Comment: how can I transfer data from running blockchain to new blockchain ?

Comment: Different question, would suggest you create a new stackoverflow question and provide more detail